# java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial ERROR

Tags: java, android

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading
> com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider uri
> content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A41
> from pid=10501, uid=10171 requires that you obtain access using
> ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs

This is what happens when I try to pick an image from "file chooser" not from "gallery".

My code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  
intent.setType("image/*");  
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "choose picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

By the way when I pick an image I tried to insert it into a database then display it on a recycler view and when it call `onBindViewHolder` method, it gives me that error...

Help please...

RecyclerAdapter.class:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.Holder> {

    private ArrayList<Employee> employees;

    public RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<Employee> employees) {
        this.employees = employees;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Holder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.employee_custom_item, null, false);
        Holder holder = new Holder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Holder holder, int position) {
        Employee employee = employees.get(position);
        holder.image.setImageURI(Uri.parse(employee.getImg()));
        holder.name.setText(employee.getName());
        holder.age.setText(String.valueOf(employee.getAge()));
        holder.hour.setText(String.valueOf(employee.getHour()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return employees.size();
    }

    class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ImageView image;
        TextView name, age, hour;

        public Holder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.employee_picture);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.employee_name);
            age = itemView.findViewById(R.id.employee_age);
            hour = itemView.findViewById(R.id.employee_hour);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no code that would produce that exception. You should of course post that code too that tries to read.

Comment: ok i will edit the post now one minute...

Comment: "I tried to insert it into a database" -- use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` instead of `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, and call `takePersistableUriPermission()` when you get your result: https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html

Comment: `holder.image.setImageURI(Uri.parse(employee.getImg()));` Is this the code that tries to read from the uri? No need to post more code then.

Comment: If you wonder why you need to change ACTION_GET_CONTENT to ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT read commonsware's book for more details :P

Answer (score 0):

When you use ACTION_GET_CONTENT to fetch content, your activity has right to use that content only.

From Commonsware's blog

> the Activity that receives the result can access the content… but not other activity instances within your app, nor any services, etc

Also, say, you store the fetched content uri in database and close the app and start the app again , you retrieve the stored uri from database and try to display in ImageView but this will result in error as now you have no rights to consume uri.
So, use ACTION_GET_CONTENT if you don't want to use the fetched content uri later. But if you do want to use the uri later, you need to use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.

```
 val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)
        intent.type = "image/*"
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Pick an Image"),PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE)
```

Inside OnActivityResult method,

```
    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE){
    Uri uri = data!=null ?: data.getData() : null;
    try{
    ContentResolver cr;
    if(uri!=null){ 
    FragmentActivity activity = this.requireActivity()
   cr = activity.getContentResolver();
if(cr!=null){
                cr.takePersistableUriPermission(uri, 
             Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)

          //now we have permission to use uri later, we can verify too
           List permission = cr.getPersistedUriPermissions();
          Log.d("myApps", "Persistable Permission =" + permission);              
          // consume here or store the uri to use later     
                 myImageView.setImageUri(uri)
    }
    }  
   
    }catch(Exception ex )
    {

    }
    }
```